Confusion on Dense set problem (Spivak, Chapter 8, Problem 6(a)), Guidance needed

A set $A$ of real numbers is said to be dense if every open interval
contains a point of $A$.

My main confusion is with problem (c), I will post my proofs for (a) and (b) for background.

(a) Prove that if $f$ is continuous and $f(x)=0$ for all numbers $x$
in a dense set $A$, then $f(x)=0$ for all $x$

Lemma: If $f(x_o)>0$ then there is some $\delta>0$ such that for every $x$ satisfying $x_o-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$, $f(x)>0$.
Suppose not, so $f(x_o)>0$ or $f(x_o)<0$ for some $x_o$ not in A. For simplicity consider $f(x_o)>0$ since the contrary is similar. By the lemma, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for every $x$ satisfying $x_o-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$, $f(x)>0$. But since A is dense there must be $x$ in $x_o-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$ that is also in $A$ such that $f(x)=0$. This is a contradiction, thus $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

(b) Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x$
in a dense set $A$, then $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x$.

This follows directly from (a) if you consider a function $h$ such that $h=f-g$. The next proof confuses me.

(c) If we assume instead that $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$ in $A$, show
that $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$. Can $\ge$ be replaced with $>$
throughout?

The case where $f(x)=g(x)$ follows from (b). Now, consider $f(x)>g(x)$. We claim that this is true. Suppose not, so $g(x_0)>f(x_o)$ for some $x_o$. Define a function $q=g-f$ This implies $q(x_0)>0$. By the lemma, there is some $\delta>0$ such that for every $x$ satisfying $x_o-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$, $q(x)>0$. But since A is dense there must be an $x$ in $x_o-\delta<x<x_0+\delta$ that is also in $A$ such that $q(x)<0$. A contradiction, thus $f(x)\ge g(x)$ for all $x$. Q.E.D
My proofs seem correct but I must be missing something, because Spivak says

It is not possible to replace $\ge$ by $>$ throughout. For example, if
$f(x)=|x|$, then $f(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the dense set $\{ x:x\neq0 \}$,
but it is not true that $f(x)>0$ for all $x$.

I understand the counterexample, but this contradicts my proof to (c). I can't figure out how to re-adjust my proof to account for this. Any advice would be appreciated.Thanks!

Let us analyze your proof of (c). We are given that $f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

The case where $f(x)=g(x)$ follows from (b).

This is correct in the sense that here we assume $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in A$.

Now, consider $f(x)>g(x)$.

It is unclear what you mean. Perhaps you want to consider the case that $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x \in A$? But then you do not treat the case in which $f(x) = g(x)$ for some $x \in A$ and $f(x')>g(x')$ for some other $x' \in A$.
Anyway, your proof can easily be made clear as follows:
Assume that "$f(x) \ge g(x)$ for all $x$" is false. Then there exists $x_0$ such that $f(x_0) < g(x_0)$. From that point your proof is correct.
Where does it break down if we know that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x \in A$ and want to show that $f(x) > g(x)$ for all $x$?
Suppose that this is not true. This means $f(x_0) \le g(x_0)$ for some $x_0$. Note that this $x_0$ cannot be contained in $A$. You can of course consider the two cases $f(x_0) = g(x_0)$ and $f(x_0)< g(x_0)$. In the second case everything works nicely and you get a contradiction, but in first case you cannot say anything. Neither the Lemma nor (b) applies.

If you're referring to my improper negation of $f(x)>g(x)$, because I had already considered the case where $f(x)=g(x)$, the problem was simply reduced to $g(x_0)<f(x_0)$ for some $x_0$.

@EdwardFalls I made an update.
